# Webrtc Ice Connection fails on IOS even when turn ice candidates are gethered.

Tags: ios, webrtc, rfc5766turnserver

I am making a video call system in webrtc and everything is working fine on web and android while the ice connection fails when calling from web to ios although ice candidates are added as visible in this chrome webrtc log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qszu.png)

Comment: can you provide the logs from iOS?